# The value of a variable just disappear

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to develop a small website in php and I have some issues with this code:

```
$idComp = $comp->id_competence;
$comp->M_deleteComp($idComp);
```

This is just a variable taking the value of the return of an object's method. If I try to read the value of `$idComp` between these two lines, it totally works. But when I use `$idComp` in the function `M_deleteComp`, it doesn't work! We have tried so many things:

- There is the good value in `$idComp`.
- We can read `$idComp` after we use it in the function (and also before).
- The function `M_deleteComp` works with a constant.
- `$comp->M_deleteComp($comp->id_competence);` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what is behind the M_deleteComp(). But one reason why the value of the $idComp changes may be because M_deleteComp() takes the reference of the actual value that you pass into and changes it.

If you are not able to access the M_deleteComp() to check the problem in more details, you may do the following:

```
$idCompTemp = $comp->id_competence;
$idComp =$idCompTemp;
$comp->M_deleteComp($idCompTemp);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering me but I have found the answer, the problem was that I was trying to get the ID of something that didn't exist. I'm sorry for having wasted your time, but thank you anyway ! =).
(I was so tired last night that I didn't figure out this ...)